# SQL records amended and expanded dynamically on dates

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Im desperately seeking a bit of help from all the Oracle SQL Guru's and Superheroes out here. Any advice and or assistance would be highly appreciated.

I have a table

**TABLE DDL and DML**

```
create table tab_A  
(item       varchar2(20),
 dest       varchar2(20),
 qty        number,
 eff        date,
 disc       date,
 eventbegin date,
 eventend   date,
 eventqty   number
);

 insert into tab_a values('item1','dest1',18,'27 July 2023','4 Sep 2023','4 Aug 2023','25 Sep 2023',6);
 insert into tab_a values('item1','dest1',30,'4 Sep 2023','2 Oct 2023','4 Aug 2023','25 Sep 2023',6);
 insert into tab_a values('item1','dest1',18,'2 Oct 2023','1 Sep 2025','4 Aug 2023','25 Sep 2023',6);
```

**Table A**

| ITEM | DEST | QTY | EFF | DISC | EVENBEGIN | EVENTEND | EVENTQTY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| item1 | dest1 | 18 | 7/27/2023 | 9/4/2023 | 8/4/2023 | 9/25/2023 | 6 |
| item1 | dest1 | 30 | 9/4/2023 | 2/10/2023 | 8/4/2023 | 9/25/2023 | 6 |
| item1 | dest1 | 18 | 2/10/2023 | 9/1/2025 | 8/4/2023 | 9/25/2023 | 6 |

**Desired output**

Newly created EFF and DISC dates should always be contiguous.

I need to adjust the dates for Eff and DISC dates based on the following

- if eff and disc dates are less than EVENTBEGIN then leave as is
- if EVENTBEGIN is between EFF and DISC then Set DISC date as EVENTBEGIN and start new ROW
- New row EVENTBEGIN becomes the new EFF and if DISC from previous row is less than EVENTEND then use previous row DISC.  The Orig_qty where EVENTBEGIN is EFF need to add EVENTQTY to ORIG_QTY.
- If EFF of the next row less than EventEnd then that is the EFF and DISC date is the lessor of CURRENT ROW DISC and EVENTEND. The Orig_qty where  EventEnd window is DISC  need to add EVENTQTY to ORIG_QTY.
- EventEnd date is the new EFF until the end of the DISC date and the qty is to remain the same.
- if the EFF is greater than EventEnd leave records as is

Newly created EFF and DISC dates should always be contiguous.

| ITEM | DEST | ORIG_QTY | EFF_DATE | DISC_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| item1 | loc1 | 18 | 7/27/2023 | 8/28/2023 |
| item1 | loc1 | 24 | 8/28/2023 | 9/4/2023 |
| item1 | loc1 | 36 | 9/4/2023 | 9/25/2023 |
| item1 | loc1 | 30 | 9/25/2023 | 10/2/2023 |
| item1 | loc1 | 18 | 10/2/2023 | 1/1/2999 |

Comment: Are you trying to physically insert/update records in your table or are you trying to generate a result set from a query? In either case I think you’d need to use code rather than pure SQL

Comment: What do you mean by "start a new row"?

Answer (score -1):

I can't see you getting around using multiple queries for this, although that shouldn't be a problem. This would probably take more than an hour to solve but I hope I can help you on your way.

You are probably gonna want to use `CASE WHEN`-expressions to handle all the ifs and buts. https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-basics/oracle-case/

You might also help solve this by using multiple queries to join into one result, since you have three rows and want six. https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-basics/oracle-union/

It seems using the `LAG()` function may be appropriate for you when handle parts of the date issues, since it looks at previous row.
https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-analytic-functions/oracle-lag/

You may also want to use a common table expression(s) (CTE), it could help simplify the queries. This is more optional and could possibly make it harder to visualize, but it's not unlikely that it'd be more performant. https://www.databasestar.com/sql-cte-with/

Comment: `DateAdd` does not exist in Oracle database,  you use wrong documentation/product. It refers to MySQL, which is also from Oracle.

Comment: Reference to DateAdd removed, thank you.